# when view visibility is set to View.GONE-layout changes its size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

How to prevent changing size of layout when its view object visibility set to View.GONE? View.INVISIBLE is not what is needed. What is needed is:

1. View object should be taken off view hierarchy.
2. Layout's size shouldn't be changed.

Comment: If you use wrap_content as any dimension for a layout an one of its child is removed, the layout size will be affected. Why can't you set the view visibility as INVISIBLE?

Comment: post your xml and what you need

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom `ViewGroup` and override [`onMeasure()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,%20int)) where you'd specify how much height/width you'd like your `ViewGroup` to have.